# Is the scene where Twilight Sparkle retrieves the Staff of Sacanas an homage to something?

Tags: my-little-pony-fim, my-little-pony

Twilight Sparkle descending from the clouds in an *angelic pose holding the Staff of Sacanas* looks really familiar. My instinct is it's a reference to an old painting.

**Where is it from?**

Comment: It seems like a fairly common (and tropey) depiction of [the Archangel Raphael's descent from heaven](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/Saint_Raphael.JPG/375px-Saint_Raphael.JPG), an image that's found in dozens of pieces of the period.

Comment: Hi if you add an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This image seems like a rendition of [The Archangel Michael Descending From Heaven (To Do Battle With The Dragon](https://biblehub.com/kjv/revelation/12.htm)), in this instance depicted by Francesco Maffei.

[image]

or

[St Raphael Descending from Heaven](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_(archangel)), in this instance depicted by Bartolomé Esteban Murillo

[image]

Variations of these poses are seen [across Western art](https://i.redd.it/w1wmt89fj5s01.jpg) where they're often mistaken (or conflated with) [images of Christ on the Cross](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1100/1*yBCu0lIXSthVAPgZpt0WpA.jpeg).